# char* conversion overload

Tags: c++, string, std

I define structure

```
struct X{
     char v;
     static int c;
     X():v(){c++};
     ~X(){c--};
     ...
};
```

and

```
typedef std::basic_string<X> xs;
```

So is there any way to use construction without explicit conversion?
I can init new string in this way:

```
xs expl_conversion((X*)"olololo");
```

But is there any way to  do it with implicit conversion?

```
xs impl_conversion("olololo");
```

May be a kind of conversion operator, but without changes in std::basic_string.

when i try use something like this:

```
X * operator X*(char* dat){ return (X*)(dat);}
```

compilator answers:

```
operator X**(char*) must be a nonstatic member function
```

So is there any way to solve the problem?
Thanx.

Comment: There are a number of unusual things in your code whose purpose I don't understand. Maybe if you explain them it will be possible to answer your question. Firstly, `"olololo"` is of type `const char*`. Why are you trying to cast it to `X*`? Secondly, why are you trying to create basic_string<X> in the first place? I'm not saying these are wrong, just unusual ... can you explain more generally what you're trying to do? Maybe there is a simpler way that doesn't involve specializing basic_string.

Comment: I want realize tracer idiom for std::string (count a quantity of operations). Simple example you can find in this repo:[link](https://github.com/korisk/tracer). It would be convenient to switch on the tracer without changing investigated source file. So I'm looking for a method for automatic substitution of std::basic_string<char> with my version.